# passing excelDefined named range in UDF in VBA

Tags: vba, function, user-defined-functions

In my excel sheet my entire column(A) i named it "myRadius" and in "A1" the cell value is 15.25. My entire column(B) i named it "myConstant" and the cell value for "B1" is 5. Then in "C1" i type some formulas which is "=myRadius*myConstant" and the result is 76.25. But when i create a VBA Function(UDF) for cleaner code and type it in "D1" the result is "#VALUE!". Here is my UDF.

```
Function ComplexCircle(myRad As Variant, myCons As Variant)
ComplexCircle = myRad * myCons
End Function
```

In "D1" i type "=ComplexCircle(myRadius,myConstant)"
Do i missing something? I did try variant/double/range parameter but it doesn't work

Comment: This isn't an answer to specific question but can you not just type in "D1" `=ComplexCircle(A1,B1)` ? Or what's wrong with good old-fashioned `=A1*B1` - why do you use the named ranges?

Comment: nope. this is just a simple and shortened formula of my current project. the real formula contains 10parameters of double/integers/string which are not namedrange, just a plain single cell value. The problem with that one is, if i will change the range of my namedrange, the old fashioned way is not applicable in a big project

Comment: I think you've quite possibly over-simplified your [mcve], and removed the bug doing so: there's no reason for *this code* to blow up *under the circumstances you're talking about*, especially if you tried explicit parameter types.

Comment: Perhaps the function is not located in a public ("regular") module?

Comment: I was a bit confused by this, I saw my version trying to evaluate $A1:$A1*$B1:$B1 - (which on a sheet works ok but not when parameters are variants or left undefined) but when the function is changed to use `double` it works fine - maybe the problem is located somewhere else in the more complex formula

Comment: also, if you're entering `=ComplexCircle(myRadius,myConstant)` that implies that you have named ranges called `myRadius` and `myConstant`.  If this is a question about basic usage of Excel then this may not be the right place for it. See the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site.